# Papyrus plugins dependecies- Classes not found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, papyrus

I am new developing plugins in eclipse, I am working with SysML models in papyrus.
When I run the plugin as an eclipse application I get some errors. Despite the errors, the plugin works as intended. I would like to know how to solve them. I think that they are related to the dependencies and runtime variables but I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

The errors are the following ( when running the project as an eclipse application)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools 4 0 2021-05-20 11:12:26.361
!MESSAGE The class org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.clazz.CreateClassDiagramCommand doesn't exist
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.clazz.CreateClassDiagramCommand cannot be found by org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml16.architecture_2.0.0.202104050115
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeFor(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeFor(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.AbstractViewTypeHelper.getPrototypeFor(AbstractViewTypeHelper.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.ViewPrototype.get(ViewPrototype.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.utils.DiagramUtils.getPrototype(DiagramUtils.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeOf(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.AbstractViewTypeHelper.getPrototypeOf(AbstractViewTypeHelper.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.ViewPrototype.get(ViewPrototype.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.util.ViewUtil.getContext(ViewUtil.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservable.<init>(NotationObservable.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservable.<init>(NotationObservable.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty$1.handleResourceLoaded(NotationObservableProperty.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.resource.ResourceAdapter$Transactional.install(ResourceAdapter.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty.hookDiagramsListener(NotationObservableProperty.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty.<init>(NotationObservableProperty.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.WelcomeModelElement.doGetObservable(WelcomeModelElement.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.modelelement.AbstractModelElement.getObservable(AbstractModelElement.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.nattable.widgets.FormTable.checkInput(FormTable.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.nattable.widgets.FormTable.setInput(FormTable.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.metadata.properties.BeanProperty.setValue(BeanProperty.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.initSegmentAttribute(ResourceLoader.java:1893)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.initAttribute(ResourceLoader.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.doCreate(ResourceLoader.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.doCreate(ResourceLoader.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.createUIElement(ResourceLoader.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.createCLRElement(Core.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.load(Core.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.load(Core.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.XWTLoader.loadWithOptions(XWTLoader.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.XWT.loadWithOptions(XWT.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.runtime.DefaultDisplayEngine.createSection(DefaultDisplayEngine.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.runtime.DefaultDisplayEngine.createSection(DefaultDisplayEngine.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.xwt.XWTSection.display(XWTSection.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.xwt.XWTSection.refresh(XWTSection.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePage.createSections(WelcomePage.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePage.createControl(WelcomePage.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePageFactory$WelcomePageModel.createPartControl(WelcomePageFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.ComponentPart.createEditorPartControl(ComponentPart.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.ComponentPart.createPartControl(ComponentPart.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createChildPart(TabFolderPart.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createTabItem(TabFolderPart.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.synchronize2(TabFolderPart.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.RootPart.synchronize2(RootPart.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabsInternal(SashWindowsContainer.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabs(SashWindowsContainer.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.createPartControl(SashWindowsContainer.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.editor.AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.activate(AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.ui.editor.CoreMultiDiagramEditor.activate(CoreMultiDiagramEditor.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.editor.PapyrusMultiDiagramEditor.activate(PapyrusMultiDiagramEditor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.editor.AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.createPartControl(AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.ui.editor.CoreMultiDiagramEditor.createPartControl(CoreMultiDiagramEditor.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:365)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools 4 0 2021-05-20 11:12:26.389
!MESSAGE The class org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.composite.CreateCompositeDiagramCommand doesn't exist
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.composite.CreateCompositeDiagramCommand cannot be found by org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml16.architecture_2.0.0.202104050115
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeFor(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeFor(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.AbstractViewTypeHelper.getPrototypeFor(AbstractViewTypeHelper.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.ViewPrototype.get(ViewPrototype.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.utils.DiagramUtils.getPrototype(DiagramUtils.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.helper.GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.doGetPrototypeOf(GMFDiagramViewTypeHelper.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.AbstractViewTypeHelper.getPrototypeOf(AbstractViewTypeHelper.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.viewpoints.policy.ViewPrototype.get(ViewPrototype.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.util.ViewUtil.getContext(ViewUtil.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservable.<init>(NotationObservable.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservable.<init>(NotationObservable.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty$1.handleResourceLoaded(NotationObservableProperty.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.resource.ResourceAdapter$Transactional.install(ResourceAdapter.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty.hookDiagramsListener(NotationObservableProperty.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.NotationObservableProperty.<init>(NotationObservableProperty.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.welcome.internal.modelelements.WelcomeModelElement.doGetObservable(WelcomeModelElement.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.modelelement.AbstractModelElement.getObservable(AbstractModelElement.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.nattable.widgets.FormTable.checkInput(FormTable.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.nattable.widgets.FormTable.setInput(FormTable.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.metadata.properties.BeanProperty.setValue(BeanProperty.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.initSegmentAttribute(ResourceLoader.java:1893)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.initAttribute(ResourceLoader.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.doCreate(ResourceLoader.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.doCreate(ResourceLoader.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.javabean.ResourceLoader.createUIElement(ResourceLoader.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.createCLRElement(Core.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.load(Core.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.internal.core.Core.load(Core.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.XWTLoader.loadWithOptions(XWTLoader.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.xwt.XWT.loadWithOptions(XWT.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.runtime.DefaultDisplayEngine.createSection(DefaultDisplayEngine.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.runtime.DefaultDisplayEngine.createSection(DefaultDisplayEngine.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.xwt.XWTSection.display(XWTSection.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.properties.ui.xwt.XWTSection.refresh(XWTSection.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePage.createSections(WelcomePage.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePage.createControl(WelcomePage.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.editor.welcome.internal.WelcomePageFactory$WelcomePageModel.createPartControl(WelcomePageFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.ComponentPart.createEditorPartControl(ComponentPart.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.ComponentPart.createPartControl(ComponentPart.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createChildPart(TabFolderPart.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createTabItem(TabFolderPart.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.synchronize2(TabFolderPart.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.RootPart.synchronize2(RootPart.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabsInternal(SashWindowsContainer.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabs(SashWindowsContainer.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.createPartControl(SashWindowsContainer.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.editor.AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.activate(AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.java:180)
    at [...]
```

Comment: Looks like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=573577) bug

Comment: Hi, it is exactly that bug. I also get the other error listed there. Is there anything that I can do it?

Comment: I don't know anything about Papyrus - just how to search Eclipse Bugzilla!